# Solving $Ax=b$ with $x\ge 0$ analytically, without formulating an optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra

For a non-square matrix $A \in R^{m \times n}$ we can solve the system $Ax=b$ with the use of the pseudo inverse matrix ($x=A^+b$). Suppose $m<n$, $A$ is a fat matrix. **Is it possible to solve for $x$ and also require that $x\ge 0$ without formulating an optimization problem?**

I am trying to solve this by using the null space of $A$, since $A$ is a fat matrix then the solution can incorporate a null space term $x_n \in N(A)$. For a given particular solution $x_p = A^+b$, how would you choose $x_{0}$ so that $x = x_p + x_n \ge 0, \forall x_i$ and $ x_n = N_A x_0 \in N(A)$ (where $N_A$ is the null space projection operator of $A$)?

Comment: This is the linear feasibility problem: you're looking for a feasible point on the intersection of an affine subspace and the positive orthant. In linear programming this requires [an additional iterative phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Finding_an_initial_canonical_tableau); there is no analytical solution as far as I know.